# Why We Choose Maven Project over Gradle Project while creating a Spring Boot Project?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, gradle

While we creating a new spring boot project in [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io/) or in Eclipse or in Intelliz why do we choose Maven Project over Gradle Project?

Comment: https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/

Answer (score 4):

It isn't related to Spring Boot in fact but rather to your general preference - whether you prefer Maven or Gradle for your project, regardless of the fact that Spring Boot is used.

Both: Maven and Gradle are well supported by Spring Boot, i.e. there are plugins for both of them to support Spring Boot projects so considering this framework - you don't lose anything regardless of your choice.

You can easily find a plenty of comparisons between these two to decide which one you prefer. Generally speaking - Gradle is newer with its advantages (flexibility given by Groovy syntax, performance etc.) and disadvantages (there are more docs and tutorials for Maven).

Answer (score 1):

You dont , you can do both ways . both have their pros and cons .

[Here](https://gradle.org/maven-vs-gradle/) is a gradle.org comparison .